# Does the scope of "נערה/Naarah" used in Mishle/Proverbs 31 include wives and/or concubines?

Tags: hebrew, marriage, mishlei, polygamy, aishes-chayil

In [Mishlei/Proverbs 31:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.31.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it states:

> She riseth also while it is yet night, and giveth food to her
> household, and a portion to her maidens.
>
> וַתָּקָם, בְּעוֹד לַיְלָה--וַתִּתֵּן טֶרֶף לְבֵיתָהּ;    וְחֹק,
> לְנַעֲרֹתֶיהָ

Does or can the word maiden or "Naarah/נערה" used in the verse denote young girls, female servants, concubines, and/or younger wives of the husband?

As always articles, commentaries, references, and personal insight are always welcomed. Todah Rabbah, Shalom Uvracah.

Comment: Too short on time for answer but see Malbim there.

Comment: @N.T. Shalom. Malbim's interpretation definitely opened my mind up to different ways of looking at the verse I never knew were possible.

Comment: That is very typical of Malbim, but in this case I think his points are obvious enough that everyone agrees.